# can't solve :undefined function get_header()

Tags: php, wordpress, header, wordpress-theming

I am trying to convert a static HTML template to WordPress template. When I try to load `index.php`, I get the following error from `header.php`:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header()in C:\xampp\htdocs\site_name\wp-content\themes\template_name\features.php on line 1

I've searched for a solution but did not find one. If someone could help me to solve this problem, I would really appreciate that.

N.B:

- I did not modify my root index.php file
- I've got the latest version of WordPress 4.3.1
- I've found that the the code i'm using directly calls a file (e.g: features.php), which is something I can't do in Wordpress. If that's the case, could anyone please tell me how to call a file without invoke this direct call.

Here is the code of my `header.php` file:

```
<li><a href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/features.php">Features</a></li>
```

Here is the `features.php` file

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="container">
<div class="row signin_visitor_you">
<div class="row signin_visitor_you_top">
....
```

Comment: The error literally tells you what is wrong.  On line 1 of `features.php`, you are calling the function `get_header()` which is not defined.  Where is `get_header()` defined?

Comment: **get_header()** is a built-in wordpress function.

Answer (score 0):

wordpress template is different with static html

you can learn to create wordpress template for begginer [here](http://goo.gl/9oB7uA)